# Write access violation c++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, access-violation

I am trying to run this code in vs 2019 but when I run the code give following error:

```
<unable to read memory>
```

this is the code:

```
// serializing config files using a stupid custom format
#define CONFIG_FILE "config.txt"
#define CONFIG_MAX_RECORDS 64
#define CONFIG_BUF_SIZE 4096
typedef struct {
    char* filterName;
    char* filterValue;
} filterRecord;
UINT filtersSize;
filterRecord filters[CONFIG_MAX_RECORDS] = {0};
char configBuf[CONFIG_BUF_SIZE+2]; // add some padding to write \n
BOOL parameterized = 0; // parameterized flag, means reading args from command line

// loading up filters and fill in
void loadConfig() {
    char path[MSG_BUFSIZE];
    char *p;
    FILE *f;
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, MSG_BUFSIZE);
    LOG("Executable path: %s", path);
    p = strrchr(path, '\\');
    if (p == NULL) p = strrchr(path, '/'); 
    strcpy(p+1, CONFIG_FILE);
    LOG("Config path: %s", path);
    f = fopen(path, "r");
    .....
```

Exception thrown: write access violation.
**p** was nullptr. occurred

Comment: Sounds like `path` doesn't contain either `'\\'` or `'/'`. Fortunately, looks like you `LOG` the variable `path`. What value does it have?

Comment: You have multiple variables named `p`, which one is the problem? Where in your code does the crash happens, on what line? And please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please refresh read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: We need a [mcve]. But I note that you have a second `char *p` declared within the `if` statement. I can't see it being used, but might it be used without being set?